# Excluding @bean from ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, spring-bean, component-scan

I have lot of beans declared in a single class

```
package com.example;
@Configuration
public class MainBeanClass{

@Override
@Bean("cachingSession")
@Lazy
public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
/**/
}

@Bean
public String createStringBean(){
 System.out.println("createStringBean has been instantiated");
}

}
```

I wanted to exclude the this bean from loading for my testCases.
In my test-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
    <context:exclude-filter><!--Not able to exclude the bean cachingSession -->
</context:component:scan>
```

is there any better way to exclude a bean on test-context.xml

Comment: @Vusal My class is getting loaded , but i wanted to exclude loading one of the bean named 'cachingSession' whereas rest of the beans in that class should still be loaded

Comment: See if the conditional spring annotations works in your case, there are these annotations available ConditionalOnBean, ConditionalOnClass, ConditionalOnExpression, ConditionalOnJava, ConditionalOnMissingBean,ConditionalOnMissingClass
etc. I am sure that will help you. Thanks